# Getting the dimensions of the uploaded image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get the dimensions of an uploaded image in ASP.NET MVC?

This is my `FileHelper` class to upload a file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace workflow.helpers
{
    public class FileHelper
    {
        private HttpPostedFileBase file {get; set;}
        public bool ValidFile { get; set;}

        public FileHelper(HttpPostedFileBase File, string Extensions, int MaxSize=1, bool IsImage = true, string Dimensions="")
        {
            this.file = File;
            validateFile(Extensions, MaxSize, IsImage, Dimensions);
        }

        public string uploadFile()
        {
            if (this.file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (this.ValidFile)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/sharedfiles/uploads/images"), fileName);
                    this.file.SaveAs(path);
                    return this.file.FileName;
                }
                else return "invalid file";
            }

            return "";
        }

        private void validateFile(string extensions, int MaxSize, bool IsImage = true, string Dimensions )
        {
                if (extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(this.file.FileName).Replace(".", "")))
                {
                    if ((((double)(file.ContentLength) / 1024) / 1024) < MaxSize)
                        this.ValidFile = true;
                }
                else
                    this.ValidFile = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But still I do not know if it is possible in to check the dimensions of the uploaded image in this class.

Comment: If linked duplicate is not enough please consider searching for title of you post to clarify why your question was not yet answered on SO: http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+Getting+the+dimensions+of+the+uploaded+image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the [link here](http://www.aspnetify.com/2014/03/get-height-width-of-uploaded-image.html) could be useful

```
private string GetImageDimension()
{
    System.IO.Stream stream = fu1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

    int height = image.Height;
    int width = image.Width;

    return "Height: " + height + "; Width: " + width;
}
```

you can get the `InputStream`, it is available as `property` in the `HttpPostedFileBase` object, easily you can get it if you write `file.InputStream`